# Nativescript: path & svg tags equivalent or how to use it (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, svg, nativescript

In Nativescript-Angular, I would like to programmatically use SVG. I don't want to display a SVG image already generated but based on the interaction with the user, the SVG has to be dynamic.

For Angular only, it's quite easy by using *svg* and *path*, just like that:

```
<div #container width="800px" height="800px">
    <svg width="100%" height="800px">

        <path d="M10 475 Q 300 475 300 250" stroke="black" fill="transparent" />
        <path d="M300 250 Q 200 250 200 125" stroke="black" fill="transparent" />
        <path d="M200 125 Q 270 125 270 10" stroke="black" fill="transparent" />

        <circle cx="270" cy="10" r="10" fill="red" />
        <circle cx="200" cy="125" r="10" fill="red" />
        <circle cx="300" cy="250" r="10" fill="red" />
        <circle cx="10" cy="475" r="10" fill="red" />

    </svg>
</div>
```

However, when I use it in Nativescript app, it's not rendering. I know that NS doesn't use webview and converts as much as possible to native apps.

Does anyone know how I could do?
Is there a way to use raw HTML? Or does NS have an equivalent?

Maybe in TypeScript, I could generate a SVG image based on the needs and update it when the user modifies it. But in that case, how to put buttons on the circles or make the circles clickable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finely, I created new SVG files with all the forms I need and then I display them using [nativescript-svg](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/@sergeymell/nativescript-svg/) and the tag SVGImage.

It's less dynamic but it's a good workaround for now and my needs.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to show raw HTML in NS. You can use the htmlview tag. For more information see the docs:
https://docs.nativescript.org/ui-and-styling.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Ashwin
However, it's not working with SVG and Path or I did something wrong?

Comment: Ok there is another way which is to use the webview tag. You can see the docs for that also.

Comment: Thanks again for your comments. I found a solution that fits better my needs. And yes I'm sure Webview would work but in my case I don't believe it was the best solution is there is. Again thx ;)